# How to use Memcached

Tags: memcached

I read a bit about **memcached** but struggling to understand how exactly we use it.

1. Is it a kind of server/application that we have to install on our
   machine?
2. Is it a script that we have to include in our web
   application and call its functions ect. when needed?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Memcached is not a script. It is a service that provides a memory cache for your applications accessible via network. It is not an out-of-the-box solution. You need to use some API to use it in your applications. So, it depends on your application.

Comment: If I install it on my Ubuntu server, does it automatically serve its purpose or do I have to enable it or do something like connection to it in my scripts of my web application? I'm using Codeigniter for PHP.

Comment: I don't know much about codeigniter. Anyway, you need to use explicitly in your application. Otherwise, it has no effect and will not do anything.